# How to persist sessions of spring boot application running on tomcat inside docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

I have a standart `Dockerfile` for my spring boot(2.2) app

```
FROM openjdk:11-slim
EXPOSE 8080
COPY ./build/libs/*.jar ./app.jar
CMD java -jar app.jar
```

There is an property in spring boot to enable session persistence (in my case on `Tomcat`)

```
server.servlet.session.persistent=true
```

Using redis seems like an overkill for my one-service application.

Maybe I can create a volume to store sessions?

Comment: Yes you could do that: "Maybe I can create a volume to store sessions?" What's your question?

Comment: Cool! I wasn't sure It's possible. Couldn't find any info about that( Can you help with a link?

Comment: Create a volume indeed, https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-docker-example/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply define the directory:

```
server.servlet.session.store-dir=/<the directory you mount as volume>
```

That's it.